# pg_dump inserting C source code in dump file

Tags: postgresql, pg-dump

Am backing up daily my DB with pg_dump. The strange issue is that when I try to restore it with psql, errors are thrown. After opening the dump file with vim and analyzing the line that is causing the error, it is clear that there is some C source code being written to the file. Not only one, but chunks of them.

How could this happen? Any way to avoid it?

The dump is done through the postgresql webmin module.

I'm using PostgreSQL 9.3.

Comment: "errors are thrown". Those errors are ....? If it's too big to paste here, include it in a pastebin link. Also show the `pg_dump` command line you use, exactly. If you run `pg_dump` directly instead of via webmin, what happens?

Comment: Just tried to dump and restore from the command line and it worked perfectly! I think it is some sort of issue with the webmin module.

Comment: Probably best post a self-answer to that effect. LMK when you do, I'll +1.

Answer (score 1):

Problem solved. Apparently there is some sort of issue with the PostgreSQL webmin module.

Dumping and restoring the DB with `pg_dump` in command line solved the issue. Will now backup with scripts rather that using webmin.